# noob with askbot: questions don't get posted

Tags: askbot

I'm trying to set up an askbot project. I have followed the instructions mentioned [here](http://askbot.org/doc/index.html) three times already (with git clone).

The problem is: I cannot post any question to the running site. I get no response when clicking on the ask question button.

Things I did differently from the tutorial were:

1. Set up the mysql user to be root instead of the one created in the tutorial because I got an inexistent user error.
2. Run a `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate`, as the prompt suggested them.
3. Set up my Base URL to be http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

Hope you guys can help out, I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried reading the JS console in your browser? What about the django logs? Try to narrow down to the origin of your problem and then give us the snippet of the part that you think is not working to your needs. Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The django console logs nothing when I click on the Ask your Question button, same as the browser console: blank. If I had an error to share I would have already posted it, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

OK - found the issue. For some reason I wasn't able to catch, there was a log in the django console saying the following:

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53242)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.13-py2.7.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 102, in **init**
>       super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in **init**
>       self.handle()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.13-py2.7.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 167, in handle
>       self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
>       data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
>   timeout: timed out

Did a `sudo pip install urllib3` (unaware why this solves the issue) and was able to post questions.

Comment: Well if this solved the problem, you should choose it as the accepted answer and close the question.